# how to detect if the function need to return a value

Tags: vb.net, function, return-value

I would like to know if it is possible to detect if a function need to return a value. 
Example :

```
dim lLayer as layer

lLayer = CreateLayer("Test")
CreateLayer("Test2")

private function CreateLayer(LayerName as string) as layer
    [...]
    if functionNeedReturn then
        return selectLayer(LayerName)
    else
        return nothing
    end if
end function
```

The first call of CreateLayer should return a value (so the if is true) and the second one should return nothing.

Is it possible to do something like this? Maybe with the system.reflection namespace...

Comment: what is `functionNeedReturn` supposed to do?  how is the code you have not able to determine if `CreateLayer` needs to return something?

Comment: "what is functionNeedReturn supposed to do", this is what I want to know. If need to do this to not have to change every calls of CreateLayer.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine whether or not the calling method is going to utilize the returned value?

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. EDIT Actually, I don't need to know if lLayer is used after the call of CreateLayer (that would be impossible I think), but I need to know if there is a lvalue when the function is called ( var = function() )

Comment: I highly doubt that there is a way to do that.  I would be shocked if there was.  Reflection would allow you to get the calling method, but it's not going to let you inspect the code inside that calling method.  If it's important to make that distinction, I would recommend adding a parameter or, better yet, make two methods, one a `Function` and one a `Sub` (e.g. `Sub CreateLayer` and `Function CreateAndGetLayer`).  However, it's hard to imagine a scenario where the distinction is beneficial.  Why not just always return the value?  What harm is there in returning it?

Comment: You can't detect what you're caller is going to do with any value you return. If there's different behaviour required, make that an input parameter.

Comment: if you had a function `ShouldCreateLayer` then the code could know whether or not to call `CreateLayer` at all.  Create could also utilize it (if its accessible)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create another function / property that determines whether `CreateLayer` will return something. It will then be up to the caller to call that first, unless he don't care receiving a null value.

However since your method is private I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're trying to protect yourself from, here.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I've misunderstood your question. In vb.net there is a [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx) keyword which *"specifies that one or more declared local variables are to continue to exist and retain their latest values after termination of the procedure in which they are declared"*

So if one is only allowed to create one instance of layer, through `CreateLayer`, one could do it as following:

```
Private Function CreateLayer(name As String, Optional ByRef returnValueIsNull As Boolean = False) As Layer

    Static isCreated As Boolean

    If (isCreated) Then
        returnValueIsNull = True
        Return Nothing
    Else
        '[...]
        isCreated = True
        returnValueIsNull = False
        Return SelectLayer(name)
    End If

End Function

'Or reversed:

Private Function TryCreateLayer(name As String, Optional ByRef result As Layer = Nothing) As Boolean

    Static isCreated As Boolean

    If (Not isCreated) Then
        '[...]
        isCreated = True
        result = SelectLayer(name)
        Return True
    End If

    Return False

End Function
```

Now, if one is allowed to create multiple layers constrained by name, one could do it as following:

```
Private Function CreateLayer(name As String, Optional ByRef created As Boolean = False) As Layer

    Static cache As Dictionary(Of String, Layer)

    If (cache Is Nothing) Then
        cache = New Dictionary(Of String, Layer)
    End If

    Dim item As Layer = Nothing

    If (cache.TryGetValue(name, item)) Then
        created = False
    Else
        '[...]
        created = True
        item = SelectLayer(name)
        cache.Add(name, item)
        Return SelectLayer(name)
    End If

    Return item

End Function

'Or reversed:

Private Function TryCreateLayer(name As String, Optional ByRef result As Layer = Nothing) As Boolean

    Static cache As Dictionary(Of String, Layer)

    If (cache Is Nothing) Then
        cache = New Dictionary(Of String, Layer)
    End If

    If (Not cache.TryGetValue(name, result)) Then
        '[...]
        result = SelectLayer(name)
        cache.Add(name, result)
        Return True
    End If

    Return False

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but for my case it would not solve my problem. My program is an add-in for ArcGIS and I am trying to avoid what seems to be a bug. The problem is that we often call SelectLayer after having called CreateLayer and then, the layer becomes locked when it should not (because we called selectlayer 2 times). I think that I will have to change all the calls of CreateLayer, otherwise it will become more complex.